# How to install oracle instant client

Tags: c++, oracle, installation, client, instant

My teacher asked to install the  oracle instant client with the instruction to run the setup.exe. However, I just couldn't find the setup.exe file after extract the zipped file. Here is all the files I got and another is the instruction.

[the instruction to run the setup.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHCBe.png)
[all the files I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdjmB.png)

Answer (score 2):

There's no setup.exe for **instant** client. You just unzip it to a directory, put that directory into PATH and off you go.

[Instant Client Installation for Microsoft Windows 64-bit](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html#ic_winx64_inst) (presuming you're on MS Windows).

Screenshot you posted refers to Oracle *client*, NOT *instant client*! - these are two separate pieces of software.

Comment: A side note for the OP: Instant Client is a bundling of the same libraries as the full client, so though they are separate, they let you do the same things. Instant Client is much easier to install, so try it first.  The one thing with Instant Client is that you need to install the VS Restributable yourself.  The Instant Client download page explains what to do.